# Removing/Escaping single quotes MySQL/JSON

Tags: python, mysql, json

I'm not quite sure which I need to do - deal with the single quotes on the MySQL side of things (on import or export) or deal with them on the JSON dump.

I have a function that SELECTS the 4 DB columns and returns them.

```
def Import_Sql():
    c, conn = connection()
    dictCursor = conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    data = dictCursor.execute("SELECT title, description, lat, lng FROM poi")
    data = dictCursor.fetchall()
    dictCursor.close
    c.close()
    gc.collect()

    return data
```

From there I do `jsonout = json.dumps(data)` which returns the following JSON

```
[{"lat": "43.8934276", "lng": "-103.3690243", "description": "Super Amazing Place", "title": "Swimming"}]
```

That all works without a flaw, however, if someone adds a DB entry that contains single quotes in the text (for example if above said "It's super amazing") I run into an issue with my Google Map no longer being able to add a marker to the point because my JSON becomes invalid.

If someone could describe to me where the issue lays, and what I can do to remedy it, I would be super happy! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to show how the JSON data is retrieved/embedded in your HTML and if the JavaScript console shows any errors.

Comment: Singles quotes in Json are perfectly valid. Maybe you are using a JavaScript implementation of Google Maps in which you put an address with simples quotes around. If that's the case you just need to escape your field before you feed it into Google Maps.

Comment: @Gab that is exactly what I am using. How do I escape the field? Can you provide an example possibly?

Comment: Hi @BrettJouwstra I created an answer to your question. If it feeds your need please upvote it and select it as the valid answer to your issue, I would appreciate it

Comment: The error I get from the console is -
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing, is having to replace the single quote and then replace the slashes that MySQL and Python were adding to the JSON with nothing, effectively removing them! Such a simple answer that took me several hours to figure out.

```
jsonout = json.dumps(MySQL_Dict)
jsonout = jsonout.replace("'", "")
jsonout = jsonout.replace("\\", "")

return render_template("all_places.html", jsonout = jsonout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following OPs comment, here is the valid answer for this question.

Json indeed supports quotes and the issue is not with the Json but with Google Map's Javascript.

The address has to have `'` escaped with `\'`.

You can do that in JavaScript with:

```
str = "It's super amazing";
str = str.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
document.write(str); // = It\'s super amazing
```